# Custom navigationBar title + animation of iOS large title

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationbar, ios11

I am currently adapting my app to iOS 11. One easy adaptation is the `prefersLargeTitles`.

In most views, this looks good and has the nice fade in animation when the view below is scrolled.

But in one view, I have a custom title view in the navigationBar. Here the title is shown all the time and it looks kind of silly to have the title visible twice and no fade in animation.

[image]

I would like the title to say "Today" in large letters while the "View by time" is visible below, and as the "View by time" scrolls up, the "Today" should slide down, become smaller and the "View by time" should fade in above it.

Can this be done? And what would be the proper handles, to hook this in?

Comment: Any solution for this?